# Guess the variation_id after add to cart form submission based on selected values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to WooCommerce and Wordpress in general. Wanted to ask you if it is possible to set WooCommerce so it will automatically guess the `variation_id` on 'Add to cart' submit. Something like this:

```
$data_store   = WC_Data_Store::load( 'product' );
$variation_id = $data_store->find_matching_product_variation( $product, wp_unslash( $_GET ) );
```

but which will work on 'Add to cart' form submission.

Is there a natively supported solution or I will have to write a custom function for this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$cart = WC()->session->get( 'cart', null );
$variation_ids = [];
foreach ( $cart as $key => $values ) {
    if ( ! empty( $values['variation_id'] ) ) {
        $variation_ids[] = $values['variation_id'];
    }
}
```

This iterates over the items in the cart and for each cart item that is a variation pushes the variation id onto the $variation_ids array.

I am not sure where you are trying to do this but if you have access to the $_REQUEST variable this is even easier - $_REQUEST['variation_id'].